# Does the dimension of a vector space tell us about vectors it contains?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, solution-verification

In particular, suppose I have a vector space W and I know that $\dim (W)$ = $0$. Does that automatically imply that $W = \{0\}$? Or does one need to go about checking the actual basis of $W$ to determine whether $W = \{0\}$?

In other words, does $\dim(W) = 0 \implies W = \{0\}$?

Please let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A $0$-dimensional vector space has only one element: its zero vector. If there were any non-zero vector $v$, then this vector by itself would constitute a one-element linearly independent family, hence would witness that $\dim W$ is at least $1$.

Comment: Ah! No doubt because $0$ is in all vector spaces, right? Thank you for clarifying!

Comment: @TRONIIX Or rather, every vector space has an element that we denote was $0$ (event though, strictly speaking, this element may be different for different spaces)